# I have two Java objects and I want to decide which i want to return at runtime

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

This is my controller class. I want to render data on choice basis, but I can return any one kind of object at a time:

```
@RequestMapping(value ="/listMessages" , produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE})
@ResponseBody
public List<FirstVersionMessageDTO> getAllMessages(@RequestParam Map<String,String> allParams) {
    if(allParams.get("version").equalsIgnoreCase("v1" ) && allParams.size()==1)
        return listMessagesService.getAllMessages("v1");    
    else if (allParams.get("version").equalsIgnoreCase("v2") )
        return listMessagesService.getAllMessages("v2");
    return null;    
}
```

I want to return object at run time. I mean there are two objects `FirstVersionMessageDTO` and `SecoundVersionMessageDTO`, but if my version is v1, then first and if it's v2, then second.

How can achieve this at runtime?

Comment: One way is to make both of them a child class of some BaseResponseDTO and then change the return type to `List<BaseResponseDTO>`.

Comment: Versions are usually determined by headers, or by seperate api paths. Having a version parameter does not conform to any rest standard and is imho a bad solution. Just wanted to inform that.

Comment: i have a situation here, ListMessages service that service should support two response versions within the same endpoint. The caller is able to define which
response version he can handle.
• Messages returned by the first version should contain only title, content and sender fields. The first
version must not accept any other parameters than the version parameter.
• Messages returned by the second version should return all 4 fields. The second version also takes a
parameter which defines the format in which the response is returned (supported formats could be
e.g. JSON and XML).

Answer (score 0):

If you really want a quick fix, then you can use generics

the method signature as below:

```
public List<?> getAllMessages(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

As Vishal mentioned in his comment, I would create one base class `MessageDTO` and let `FirstVersionMessageDTO` and `SecondVersionMessageDTO` extend this base class.

The method should then be adapted to return a `List` of `MessageDTO`:

```java
public List<MessageDTO> getAllMessages(@RequestParam Map<String,String> allParams) {
[...]
}
```

*Additional info:*

If both classes share common functionality, you should probably also put this common functionality in the base class.